# Tab badge only works when notification is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM (GCM) for my notifications and this can be display both in foreground and background mode.

I'm updating the badge on my tab controller via the notification center if the user is inside the app the badge appears and so if a notification is received and the user clicks it the badge also appears in the tab bar.

The issue I'm having is that if the user is outside the app and it doesn't click immediately the notification once you go back to the app by clicking the icon or double clicking the home button the badge is not there. How can I achieve such functionality?

**App delegate**

```
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        let content = notification.request.content
        print("userNotification willPresent")
        print(content.userInfo)
    }

    // Only display the notification outside the chat log controller
    if self.window?.rootViewController?.topViewController is ChatLogController {
        completionHandler([])
    } else{
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        let tab = self.getTopViewController() as? UITabBarController
        tab?.tabBar.items![1].badgeValue = "!"
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
    }
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        print("userNotification didReceive")
    }

    let tab = self.getTopViewController() as? UITabBarController
    tab?.tabBar.items![1].badgeValue = "!"

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    goToChatView()

    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: you should try with `willPresent notification` of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` This will be trigger when the alert is presented and so you can check the data and set appropriate values

Comment: I'm using willPresent in the comment above you can see it or do you mean another thing? @kathayatnk